# What would be the dual of the space $C^2 [0,1]$ under the norm $W^{1,1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, optimal-control

Let $C^2 [0,1]$ be the space of all twice continuously differentiable functions on the compact interval $[0,1]$. Equip $C^2 [0,1]$ by the norm $W^{1,1}$, that is 
$$   \|f\| := \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)| \; dt +   \int_{0}^{1} |f'(t) | \; dt        $$

Under this norm, clearly $C^2 [0,1]$ becomes a normed subspace of $W^{1,1}$, which is equivalent to $AC[0,1]$, however it is no longer a banach subspace.

My question is that what would be the dual of the space $C^2 [0,1]$ under above norm?

Comment: Fact: if $X$ is a normed space and $E$ is dense in $X$, then $X^* = E^*$ (i.e. there is a natural isometric isomorphism between them, given by restriction / continuous extension).  Now  $C^2([0,1])$ is dense in $W^{1,1}([0,1]) = AC[0,1]$.  So the dual of $C^2([0,1])$ in the $W^{1,1}$ norm will be equal to the dual of $W^{1,1}([0,1])$ itself.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you. Is there any reference showing that $C^2$ is dense in $W^{1,1}$?

Comment: I don't know a reference offhand, but it's pretty standard.  One approach is via convolution.  Another is this: you know, I suppose, that $C^1([0,1])$ is dense in $L^1$.  Since $f' \in L^1$, choose a sequence $h_n \in C^1([0,1])$ with $h_n \to f'$ in $L^1$.  Set $g_n(t) = \int_0^t h_n(s)\,ds$, so that $g_n \in C^2$.  You may verify that the sequence $g_n$ is Cauchy in $W^{1,1}$, and that $f-g$ is a constant a.e.; call the constant $c$.  Then $g_n + c \to f$ in $W^{1,1}$.